# what is the correct way to make the output streaming operator work for a boost::variant<std::vector<int>, int, double>

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-variant

`boost::variant` implements a streaming operator for itself.
The problem is that there is none for `std::vector<>` -- but `boost::variant` assumes that there is one implemented for every one of the types passed to `boost::variant`. So where to implement this operator? Preferably in some namespace, where it does not collide with other people implementation.
From what I understand one can either implement

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::vector<T>&);
```

in the `std` namespace or in the namespace in which the streaming operator of `std::vector` is being called from -- in this case `boost::detail::variant`

I don't like neither. Any other way?

Comment: I guess it depends whether you are going to write a generic templated vector streamer or a streamer for a vector of a particular content type. If the content is your own type then it shouldn't conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Adding stuff in namespace `std` is **U**ndefined **B**ehavior.

Adding stuff in foreign namespace is not fine, even if legal. but it would not solve your issue with ADL anyway (`template <typename T> std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::vector<T>&);` only use `std` for ADL (and namespace for `T`))

Fragile fix would be to put it in global namespace, but then you have to include it before boost `operator <<` definition :-/

As alternative, you might use regular way to handle `variant` and use visitor:

```
struct Printer
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator() (const T& e) const { std::cout << e; }

    template <typename T>
    void operator() (const std::vector<T>& v) const
    {
        // Your implementation, such as
        for (const auto& e : v) {
            std::cout << e << std::endl;
        }
    }

};


boost::visit(Printer{}, my_variant);
```

Comment: UB: uncle bob? 
University of Botswana?

Comment: @FrankPuck: **U**ndefined **B**ehavior

Answer (score 0):

You can override `operator<<` only for particular types

```
template<typename ...Args>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, boost::variant<std::vector<int>, Args...> t);
```